# .htaccess переадресация с папки на поддомен

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, redirect, apache2

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы при заходе по адресу *http://site.com/sub* или *http://www.site.com/sub* переадресовывало на *http://sub.site.com*?

В корневом каталоге располагается файл .htaccess с содержимым

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php?route=error/_400
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php?route=error/_401
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?route=error/_403
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?route=error/_404
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?route=error/_500
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)$ http://sub.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^sub$ http://sub.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

В папке **sub** располагается файл .htaccess с похожим содержимым

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php?route=error/_400
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php?route=error/_401
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?route=error/_403
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?route=error/_404
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?route=error/_500
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Так же имеется вопрос, можно ли как то из папки sub в файле .htaccess обратиться к файлу из корневой директории, например, *RewriteRule ^style/([@.A-Za-z0-9-/+_=]+)$ ../library/styles/$1 [L]* ?


Пытаюсь сделать следующее

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php?route=error/_400
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php?route=error/_401
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?route=error/_403
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?route=error/_404
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?route=error/_500
#
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_VHOST} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.site\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub/index.php?route=$1 [L,E=VHOST:1]
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$
#RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)$ http://sub.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
#RewriteRule ^sub$ http://sub.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Не работает перенаправление с site.con/sub на sub.site.com (циклическая переадресация), а так же при переходе, например, на sub.site.com/abc - ошибка 500, кто знает, что нужно исправить?

Comment: Простите за оффтоп. Но вот почитать про mod_rewrite http://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но мне нужно чтобы правила для поддомена были записаны в корневом .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

В файле .htaccess нужно прописать:

```
Redirect 301 /sub http://sub.site.com
```

Comment: а зачем первые две строчки?

Comment: на всякий случай, чтобы потом добавить что либо еще

Comment: полагаю, в таком случае имеет смысл описать ваши намерения и рассказать, как работает этот кусочек конфигурации

Answer (score 0):

Не рекомендовал бы использовать в домене `www`, его сейчас мало кто использует:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

И решение Вашей проблемы будет выглядеть так:

```
Redirect /sub http://sub.site.com
Redirect http://www.site.com/sub http://sub.site.com
```